# Monitoring of statistics in Google Recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

is there a way to monitor the statistics that are presented in the Google Recaptcha admin panel? Api or any other way? Or i can only see them in the admin panel?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could access them only via admin. If you want to do some other visualisation, you could download the CSV file and import it into your own system.

I hope this helps!